# Partitions Grub UEFI GPT MBR

Tags: grub2, uefi, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I'm having a problem with the partitions in my system. Yesterday, I wanted to try Arch Linux, so I installed it in a new partition and in the process I was told, since my system is UEFI, I had to create a new partition to put the boot files there. So, I created a partition of 512 MB and put it there.
However, grub couldn't start and nothing worked. I suspect that the problem was that the partition scheme in my system is MBR and not GPT, since I used to have a partition with Windows.

I deleted everything and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS again and now the system works. However, in my BIOS I can still see the boot partition I created and select to start from it, even though I deleted it. How can I solve this ? Also, since GPT is better and the way foward, I would like to convert my partitions to this scheme. Is it possible to do it from Ubuntu with loosing information ?

Any help would be really appreciated. THanks

EDIT: So, I deleted everything and created the everything from the grounds as GPT. However, I can still see previous grubs partition in the BIOS. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe you can convert but is much better to backup, totally repartition and restore from backups. You should have backups running anyway. If you do convert you need an efi partition for UEFI boot and it should be first or at least near beginning of drive. And/or is booting in BIOS mode from gpt then grub needs a bios_grub partition. You have to reinstall grub, and Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI, so either system is UEFI or you do not want Windows. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: I don't need Windows. I can do a backup to another hard drive and delete this hard drive and do everything from the beginning. I don't know if that is going to solve the problem of the bios detecting boot partitions that don't existe anymore though. 
So, I should: 1. delete all the partition in the hard drive  2. create a new partition table that uses GPT   3. create the first partition as a 512 MB fat32.    4. create the rest of the partitions.

Comment: There should be a good way to change a drive from MBR to GPT without deleting everything, it's just the first few sectors of a drive. A program like `testdisk` can sometimes recover partitions, I wonder if it might work to recover them after changing from MBR to GPT and not creating or deleting anything else on the drive?

Comment: If you have UEFI, it has its own NVRAM, so it remembers old settings. You have to remove folder from old install in an efi partition, then use efibootmgr to delete UEFI entry. BIOS should not show old installs if partitions have been deleted as grub cannot find them.

Comment: I deleted everything and created the everything from the grounds as GPT. However, I can still see previous grubs partition in the BIOS. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The partitioning a GPT disk is to proceed to:

Delete the msdos partition table.

Create a gpt partition table

Create a bootloader partition.

Create a swap partition.

Create a linux partitions.

Create other data partitions.

There are two options to format the boot sector of a GPT disk.

```
 Your machine is (U)EFI aware via the Bios and turned on,
```

and selected to be bootable,You wish to use EFI to boot a GPT disk formatted disk,

you must have a FAT formatted EFI System Partition (type EF00 ) as the first partition

```
Your machine is not (U)EFI aware via the Bios, You wish to use
```

the Bios to boot a GPT formatted disk, you must make a Bios boot partition,

(type EF02) as the first partition. The Boot Bios partition is not to be formatted